# Convert string to variable name to use in jQuery .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be easy but I cannot find the answer.

I have five location values stored in variables: navA, navB, navC, etc.

When user clicks a link, I wish to animate moving a div to that location:

```
$('myDiv').animate({
    'left': navB
},2000);
```

This works. However, when user clicks the link, all I receive is the first letter -- I need to prefix 'nav' to the letter to get either navA or navB etc

How do I create the variable name, and use it in the animate function?

I tried:

```
$('theLink').click(function(){
    var nextLoc = $(this).attr('id').charAt(0); //returns A or B or C or...
    var nextVar = 'nav'+nextLoc;

    $('myDiv').animate({
        'left': nextVar
    },2000);

});
```

Comment: Protip: `$(this).attr('id')` === `this.id` but `this.id` is much faster because it's native JS.

Comment: Excellent point, Sterling. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use window object to access global variables

```
var nextVar = window['nav'+nextLoc];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use eval method of javascript..

```
var nextVar = eval('nav'+ nextLoc);
```